# Python Flask SQl Alchemy / SQLite database design

Tags: python, sql, flask

I'm currently designing an application on Flask using bootstrap and various flask plugins with a view eventually hosting on heroku.  The app is essentially a modern punch card . Employees can log in , clock in and out their shift and view what they've worked in past weeks , months and an estimation of how much money they've earnt during those times. The dB is then going to be exportable via text file to admin.

I've managed to code login and register functionality that save user input to a database I've created using alchemy.

However the base function of the app is where I'm struggling , I'm not great with databases. Each user should be able to login and then clock in to start their working shift / clock out and view reports of previous day's worked .

I can't seem to find any way to ensure that when a user logs in and clocks in or out and creates an Hour object to save that to a table specific to the user that no one but that user or an admin can see?

I will post code first thing tomorrow but my issue summarised is :

I can't seem to work out how to ensure a user logged in creates data that relates only to him/herself that can't be viewed by other users ( obviously as it's their own hours their peers don't need to see it ) . I have tried setting the FK to user Id but to no avail i cant seem to link the tables .

I know using SQLite as my dB will potentially cause issues when i deploy to heroku and use postgresql instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table where you log when users clock in and clock out, with an id field (primary key), an action field (clock in or out) and a date time field; then create another table, which will be secondary to the user and logging table, with 2 columns: user_id and logging_id, foreign keys to users.id and logging.id respectively.

You need then to map them as you know how to do it in flask-sqlalchemy (for the "secondary" table you need to use the db.Table function, not create a class; look at this unrelated [example](http://flask-security.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html): you need to map your 'logging_users' secondary table like the 'roles_users' in the example.)

Then you need to create a relationship between the classes: to your User class add

```
logging = db.relationship ('Logging', secondary=logging_users, 
                              backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Now every user instance will have an associated 'logging' field, which is a list that contains every logging instance associated with the specified user. You can add a logging instance to an user by append it to its logging field, like you would do with every list element; example:

```
log = Logging(action='enter', datetime='2017-04-04T08:14:23')
current_user.append(log)
```

I hope I'm clear!

Answer (score 0):

you should use session to manage user sessions. Also consider the following database model:

```
class User:
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    logged_in = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    logged_out = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

your variables will look like:

```
data = User.query.filter(User.username == session['username']).first()
user_username = data[0]
user_password = data[1]
user_logged_in = data[2]
user_logged_in = data[3]
```

as you can see, the "data" object is only retrieved by the user in session which can be defined by the framework you use, or by yourself  when getting the POST data from the login form.

Hope this helps